# Cant search with values sent by serial monitor VB.NET 2017 using MYSQL

Tags: php, vb.net

```
Private Sub txtRFID_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtRFID.TextChanged

        Try


            Dim search As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `rfid`=@rfid", connection)
                search.Parameters.Add("@rfid", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtRFID.Text

                Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(search)

                Dim table As New DataTable()
                Dim imgByte() As Byte

                adapter.Fill(table)



                lblMName.Text = table(0)(5)
                lblFName.Text = table(0)(4)
                lblLName.Text = table(0)(3)
                lblCourse.Text = table(0)(10)
                lblYear.Text = table(0)(11)
                imgByte = table(0)(12)

                Dim ms As New MemoryStream(imgByte)
                PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)


                adapter.Dispose()


        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Card not registered in database !")
            txtRFID.Text = ""
            returnStr = ""
        End Try


    End Sub
```

Here is my code for searching record , i can search it when i copy paste the rfid code in the "txtRFID.text". But when i swipe an RFID card it does nothing and return error wherein the serial monitor return the exact value to the "txtRFID.text" textbox.

Heres the code of my serial monitor read :

```
Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        Dim id As String = SerialPort1.ReadLine()
        returnStr &= id
        txtRFID.Text = returnStr
    End Sub
```

and the declaration for returnStr

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim returnStr As String
    Dim connection As New MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=xxxxx") ....
```

Comment: What is the error message and where in the code does the error occur?

Comment: Hi @Mary ! Thank you for your response. I managed to get it working now , apparently , 

"Dim id As String = SerialPort1.ReadLine()
        returnStr &= id
        txtRFID.Text = returnStr"

this piece of code is returning a value with an invisible character at the end . So instead of something like , "ABCDE" it returns a string with a value of "ABCDE" to the textbox. It looks the same on first look but when you click the textbox and hit backspace it deletes nothing , and if you press it again it deletes "E". So an invisible character is there , or a newline whitespace i dont know.

Comment: Actually it was our professor who pointed out what could be the problem , and he was right. TRIM function did the trick and delete the whitespace. So the code looks like this now, Dim id As String = SerialPort1.ReadLine()
        returnStr &= id.Trim()
        txtRFID.Text = returnStr

Comment: I am glad you got it working and welcome to Stack Overflow.